# Is there any meaning to distinguish spend in / spend on?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I am a Chinese. The usage of the **spend** is :

- spend sth(money or time) in doing
- spend sth(money or time) on sth

I think this rule is quite tedious. 
If I just use in or on for the both situation above, will cause the grammar error from the aspect of the native speaker?

Comment: One spends money in a location, like a store, a city, or a country. One spends money on a product or on a person (really, on a product for a person). Other uses will sound wrong to native speakers.

Comment: Compare (1) *he spent $5 in his efforts to set up the project* (2) *he spent $5 on his efforts to set up the project*. To my ear, #1 refers to money incidental to setting up the project, while #2 refers to expenditures related to setting up the project. Also, *he* and *his* refer to the same person in #1; they might be different in #2. Furthermore, you could replace *spent* with *found* in #1 and still have a meaningful sentence; doing that with #2 doesn't work.

Comment: What @Lawrence said. In a context such as *The candidate spent far too much in his electoral campaign*, the (relatively less common) preposition ***in*** represents a more *metaphorical* usage (it represents the campaign as a "physical, *containing* area* within which the money was spent), where the more idiomatic ***on*** simply alludes to what was bought ***with*** the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Davo didn't quite understand you above. You meant the difference between *spend sth in* and *spend sth on* with regard to actions. Someone told you *in* is only used for ~ing verbs and *on* is only used for nouns.

In reality, that's horsepuckey. The only differences between *spend ~ eating lunch*, *spend ~ in eating lunch*, and *spend ~ on eating lunch* is (a) the first one is more common than the other two and (b) they mean something a little different. None of them are wrong, although you should follow your teachers' rules if they're grading you.

Davos is right in his two uses for money but you can spend time or money in the performance of an action as well. To spend time or money on the performance of an action is minutely different. It denotes the time/money was spent for the action but not necessarily in the act itself and leaves open the option that you had another perform the action on your behalf.

The grammar for both are the same, however, because they're both prepositions and the verb has to be rephrased as a noun to act as the preposition's object.

**More importantly**, English has no word for 中國人 now that "Chinaman" is a slur. "Chinese" can only be used as an adjective: "I'm a Chinese *student*", "I'm Chinese", &c. but not ever "I'm a Chinese".

**Similarly**, in reference to a word *as* a word, it's uncountable (不可数的) and ideally set off by italics (*spend*) or quotes ("spend"). It's "both situation**s**", not "both situation". Getting a better grasp of countable things and uncountable stuff is going to help you much more on your tests than the distinction you're asking about.